# moment-timezone America/Sao_Paulo wrong timezone offset

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm getting an error using `moment-timezone` with `America/Sao_Paulo` trying to parse date with `America/Sao_Paulo` offset. I've created this code:

```
const date = "2019-1-1 23:30";
const format = "YYYY-M-D HH:mm";
const timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo";
const dateMoment = moment.tz(date, format, timezone);
```

The output of `dateMoment` is `2019-01-01T23:30:00-02:00` but I expect `2019-01-01T23:30:00-03:00`, since `America/Sao_Paulo` has offset `-03:00`.

Am I missing something or did I initialize `dateMoment` wrong?

```js
const date = "2019-1-1 23:30";
const format = "YYYY-M-D HH:mm";
const timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo";
const dateMoment = moment.tz(date, format, timezone);

console.log(dateMoment.format());
console.log(moment.tz(timezone).format('Z'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: The output is correct, see [Sao Paulo DST Changes](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo), the offset in June is `-03:00` while the offset is `-02:00` in January.

Comment: This has been fixed in moment/timezone 0.5.27 build. Upgrade your moment-timezone lib/js to see the effect.

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/tree/develop/builds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On January 1st 2019, [Sao Paulo was still on Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2019).  It was UTC-2 until February 17th.

[Brazil abolished summer time going forward](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-scraps-dst.html), but that hadn't taken effect yet.